# Java not executing commands in Linux

Tags: java, linux, user-interface, command-line

I'm making a GUI for a CLI program and when this event is activated the `jLabel4` text instantly changes to `Task: Finished Exporting`.

Why is the `.exec(...);` command not working? It's not the command syntax, I tried replacing my command with `touch new.file` and that doesn't work either.

To me it seems like it doesn't event try to execute the command.

Java Code:

```
private void jMenuItem2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    if (ext[1].equals("iso") || ext[1].equals("wbfs")) {
        String tmpPath = "";
        if (jtPath.indexOf(".") > 0)
             tmpPath = jtPath.substring(0, jtPath.lastIndexOf("."));

        Process p;
        try {
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wit extract \"" + jtPath + "\" \"" + tmpPath + "\"");
            p.waitFor();
            jLabel4.setText("Task: Exporting...");
            p.destroy();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        System.out.println("wit extract \"" + jtPath + "\" \"" + tmpPath + "\"");

        jLabel4.setText("Task: Finished Exporting");
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You can only extract .iso and .wbfs file formats.");
    }
}
```

Command Line Output:

```
wit extract "/home/adam/Wii Hacking/NSMBW SMNE01.wbfs" "/home/adam/Wii Hacking/NSMBW SMNE01"
```

Comment: For one, you're not handling the process's streams at all, risking you running out of buffer space and not recognizing command line error messages. For another your code runs afoul of Swing threading rules.

Comment: Also, you need to capture and evaluate the int returned from `p.waitFor();`.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Exit value is 27, don't know what that means.

Comment: It should exit with 0. Check the wit documentation to see what this value means. And do handle the processes InputStream and ErrorStream to see if any useful information is returned and to prevent running out of buffer memory.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Error 27 is "Can't open file" but when I execute the same command from the terminal instead of java it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the problem is the space in the file name or, more exactly, that quotes do not work in the command string since it is not processed by a shell.

Try using the `exec` method that accepts an array of strings:

```
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"wit", "extract", jtPath, tmpPath});
```

And still do handle standard output and error.

Comment: Also have a look at `java.lang.ProcessBuilder` - it is a bit newer and has some nice utility methods for redirecting input/output.